# Spring boot : How to make ContentType header purely optional? It throws a HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException if not passed

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I want my application to work even when ContentType header is not passed. The request body in my case is always a JSON. But the below code always throws an exception

> *org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' not supported*

```
public class UserController {
    @PostMapping(value = "/updateUser", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<?> updateUserDetails(@RequestBody User user) {
        //Do something
    }
```

This was expected, but even after creating a custom config, it gives the same error:

```
@Configuration
public class MyWebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.defaultContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    }
}
```

This works fine if I pass the ContentType header which i want to make purely optional. Please help.

Comment: Have you tried to add annotation @EnableWebMvc in your configuration class ?

Comment: Is your controller class marked with the @RestController annotation?

Comment: @Andrian : Yes. It's annotated with RestController and I did try the EnableWebMvc tag in the config. No luck though.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may occur because the **User** object cannot have any getters / setters

Comment: It has all the getters and setters including a no argument constructor. Note that it works fine if i pass the content type header. Meaning the conversion is not the problem here.